# Как избавится от окна: "Проверьте свои пароли"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios

При регистрации на сайте выплывает такое окно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запросы на сервер происходят в таком виде:

```
import * as axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: 'api',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})

export const API = {
    signAPI : {
        signUp: (email, password, name, surname, username) => {
            return instance.post(`users/sign`, {email, password, name, surname, username})
                .then(response => {
                    return response
                })
        },
}
```

Возможно нужно передать какие-то дополнительные хеадеры?

Comment: А вы хоть читали, что там написано?

Comment: Произошла  утечка данных. Где? Каким образом?

Comment: Это механизмы безопасности chrome, отключить нельзя. В сообщении говорится, что пара логин/пароль были скомпрометированы (не на вашем сайте, а в целом). Введите другой более сложный пароль, и окна не будет. [Подробнее о защите](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10311524?hl=ru#zippy=%2C%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%2C%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

Comment: да, спасибо. От 8 символов работает нормально